# Use strings with map and colnames in R

Tags: r

I use this code to list the name of some variables in my R environment.

```
> IDs <- grep("_temp", ls(), value = T, invert = T)
```

```
> str(IDs)
```

char [1:2] "X" "Y"

Next, I tried to use this IDs to find the colnames with map

```
IDs %>%
   map(~ colnames(.x))
```

However, this does not work because both X and Y are inside the "" -> "X" and "Y". Which makes the command be like this:

```
 colnames("X")
```

What do I need to do to make the command to run like this:

```
colnames(X)
```

Comment: You can use `mget` on a character vector to get a list of the actual objects, so in your case `IDs |> mget() |> map(colnames)` should work